# Why is the value not updating in this Angular Select list?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a select list of people.

```
     <div *ngIf="people">
        <label>Tuoja</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="person" name="person" required>
          <option *ngFor="let person of people" [value]="person.PersonID">
            {{person.FirstName}} {{person.LastName}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

When the form is submitted, it will send a `ngForm` object to the typescript class:

```
  sendNewMovie(movieForm: NgForm): void {
     console.log(movieForm.value.person); // this is object
     console.log(movieForm.value.movieName); // this is string
     console.log(movieForm.value.movieDetails); // this is string
}
```

sendMovie function gives me this in the console, the first console log is undefined but the others work:

```
undefined // this doesn't work

moviename // this works

moviedetails // this works
```

Comment: May be because you have `sendNewMovie`, not `sendMovie`?

Comment: Edited the post, I have other fields in the form as well, they are just plain values and they seem to be working fine. However the one that is object returns undefined. Is it because you can't assign an object to NgForm.value?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
<div *ngIf="people">
    <label>Tuoja</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="person" name="person" required>
      <option *ngFor="let person of people" [value]="person.PersonID">
        {{person.FirstName}} {{person.LastName}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

In the component

```
console.log(movieForm.value.person);
console.log(movieForm.value.movieName);
console.log(movieForm.value.movieDetails);
```

Outputs

```
2

moviename

moviedetails
```